# Identity of the clicked id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

i am using php codeigniter. I am sending data in an array to my view. In my view i have a foreach loop in place which iterates through the array and displays the data in my view. Also inside this foreach loop i am displaying some action buttons.

```
 <?php
     foreach($studentList as $r)
      {
       echo '<tr>';
       echo $r->id;
       echo '</tr>'?>
     <a class="lock" data-id="<?= $r->id?>_lock" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Lock Profile" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="clip-locked"></i></a>
     <a class="hidden unlock" data-id="<?= $r->id?>_unlock" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Unlock Profile" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="clip-unlocked"></i></a>
 <?php   
       } ?>
```

What i want to do is to display the lock button by default, when someone clicks on this button lock should get hidden and unlock button should get displayed. in my jquery i am doing it like this but clicking on single button accounts for changing the buttons on the whole page.
I know the reason as i am accessing the element using class which all of them have common but i haven't yet figured out how to do that using id which will account for single elements.

```js
$('.unlock').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
  console.log(id);
  $('.unlock').addClass("hidden");
  $('.lock').removeClass("hidden");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This slight modification should help you.

```
$('.unlock').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("data-id").split('_')[0];
        console.log(id);
        $(this).addClass("hidden");
        $('[data-id='+id+'_unlock]').removeClass("hidden");
    });
```

Comment: your code will fail, your last selector wont match to any elements, it will hide the clicked elements and wont show any.

Comment: @Kstro21, sorry. I have edited the code now. Had added that answer from my mobile on the go.

Comment: instead of using $('.lock[data-id='+id+'_unlock]').removeClass("hidden"); i used $('[data-id='+id+'_unlock]').removeClass("hidden"); solved my problem. Please edit the answer, i have accepted it but if anyone else is having the same problem should get it correct. Thanks!!

Comment: @umair.ashfr, Thanks. Done!!

Answer (score 0):

OK, so first off, you're putting the anchors outside of the `<tr>`'s. Is this intended?

If you have code like this:

```
 <?php
     foreach($studentList as $r)
      {
       echo '<tr>';
       echo $r->id;?>
     <a class="lock" data-id="<?= $r->id?>_lock" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Lock Profile" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="clip-locked"></i></a>
     <a class="hidden unlock" data-id="<?= $r->id?>_unlock" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Unlock Profile" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="clip-unlocked"></i></a>
 <?php   
       echo '</tr>';
       } ?>
```

You can simply do:

```
$('.unlock').click(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
            console.log(id);
            $(this).parent('tr').find('.unlock').addClass("hidden");
            $(this).parent('tr').find('.lock').removeClass("hidden");
        });
```

Also have a look [here](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) on information on how to fetch siblings, as an alternative way to locate the element you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your html is semantically wrong, `tr` should contain `th` or `td` depending of what you want to do. Even when the browsers doesn't complaint for bad html doesn't mean it is correct. So, this is what a recommend:

Supposing we have this

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach($studentList as $r) { ?>
        <?php echo '<tr><td>'; ?>
        <?php echo $r->id; ?>
        <a class="lock" data-id="<?= $r->id?>_lock" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Lock Profile" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="clip-locked"></i></a>
        <a class="hidden unlock" data-id="<?= $r->id?>_unlock" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Unlock Profile" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="clip-unlocked"></i></a>
        <?php echo '</td></tr>'; ?>
    <?php  } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Bind a single event to both anchors:

```
$("#myTable tr a").click(function(){
    //save the element for future reference and avoid repeat $(this)
    var elm = $(this),
        id = elm.attr("data-id"),
        elmtoShow = elm.hasClass('unlock') ? '.lock' : '.unlock';

    console.log(id);

    elm.addClass("hidden");

    //we can pass a second param to jQuery to query into 
    //that single element instead the whole document
    $(elmtoShow, this.parentNode).removeClass("hidden");
});
```

Please, note that I added an `id` to the table to make the query to all anchors, also read the comments in the code. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Kstro for identifying the errors in my html, i have made the changes as you suggested and lesson learned. Thank you